# Store each highlightes selection on an array Vanilla Js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have dummy text and I wish to store each highlighted text selection on an array with vanilla javascript.

This my first trial for displaying a single select in another a textarea tag.

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure sed ea aperiam voluptas error assumenda iusto, sequi unde non, nesciunt autem. Atque eveniet delectus tenetur nostrum quaerat explicabo debitis iste.
Ipsa a nobis voluptatem dolores ducimus reiciendis iste unde, dolorum ut eveniet inventore consequatur illum provident similique quas rem quidem odit officiis eaque illo impedit tenetur quam atque ab! Velit!
Commodi voluptas saepe cupiditate mollitia. Dolores delectus explicabo laborum exercitationem suscipit ullam quod dignissimos molestiae? Animi, commodi quod vel nesciunt ab possimus nostrum explicabo fugiat tenetur magni dolor illo aliquam?
</div>

<textarea
 type='text'
 id='input'>
</textarea>

<script>
var text = []
function gText (e) {
 text = (document.all) ? document.selection.createRange().text : document.getSelection()
 document.getElementById('input').value = text
}
document.onmouseup = gText
if (!document.all) document.captureEvents(Event.mouseup)
</script>
```

Now I guess that I need to push each selection on an the array with a
foreach loop but I really have no idea how to do this without jquery. Any help please?

Comment: How would jQuery help you push an element into an array?

Comment: Instead of using `document.all`, check whether the features you want actually exist.

Comment: @Blender Sorry for the misunderstood and thank you for your time.I wasn't meaning using jQuery for this operation only but, globally on my project, jQuery is not allowed for those who can provide a help with it that's it. :)

Comment: @SLaks Thank you for your time. That's why I came here as I found no serious documentation about the subject yet. If you have anything please share.

Comment: Would this work? `var arr = []

function gText (e) {
 var text = (document.all) ? document.selection.createRange().text : document.getSelection();
 document.getElementById('input').value = text;
 arr.push(text);
}` May be i'm missing something ...

Comment: @mike123 thank you for your time but Drongo had the final word! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to store the value of any selection made on a page? If so...

```
<script>

/**
* Store selection in an array and only store same value once.
*/

var selectionArray = [];

function storeSelection(e){
    var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
    if(selectedText.length && selectionArray.indexOf(selectedText) === -1){
        selectionArray[selectionArray.length] = selectedText;
    }
    console.log(selectionArray);
}   
document.addEventListener('mouseup', storeSelection);

</script>
```

Comment: This exactly what I needed. It always look obvious when I got help but it is still impressive ;) Thank you for your time Drongo! you rock 5*